# How do I change an if-else statement into a toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have black text that when double clicked, changes to a different color. I want it to be able to change back to black on a double click. Right now, I have:

```
<script>
<h1 id="color"> I CHANGE COLORS! </h1>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ondblclick="
        counter++;
        if(counter%2==1){color()} else {black()}
        ">Double click here</a>
</script>
```

The two functions called are `color()` and `black()`. Is there anyway I can use a toggle instead of this if-else with javascript?

Comment: 1 - counter is more "toggly" than counter++

Comment: The code you have appears to work as a toggle already. Other than your event handlers being declared with inline HTML, I see no problems here.

Comment: @meagar: How about "your code could be improved by..." instead of the unhelpful "this is junk"? I bet you learned somewhere, too (and chances are it was using attributes as well). -- **Jay**: have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/Xgrbf/1/

Comment: thanks brad! i just started with javascript a couple weeks back haha, still trying to learn. meagar, if you could enlighten me about how you would go about it, maybe that would help me out more..

Comment: @Jay Your best bet would be to go with jQuery or a similar DOM manipulation library, but you've arbitrarily ruled this out. You can still learn JavaScript while letting jQuery normalize your interface to the DOM. As it stands, your code introduces a global variable with an extremely generic name, uses `href="javascript:...` and has inline JavaScript, all of which are known to lead to code which is error-prone, terrible to maintain and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the functions in a globally accessible object:

```
functions = {};
functions[true] = black;
functions[false] = color;

black = true
```

And then invert your state flag:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ondblclick="
        black = !black;
        functions[black]();
        ">Double click here</a>
```

While this satisfies your very arbitrary requirements, it's a hideous solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the `anchor` element's properties to carry the toggle value for you (for example it's `ID`). Then you'd be able to include all of the necessary code in a single `ondoubleclick` event without the need to declare the toggle variable beforehand:

```
<h1 id="color"> I CHANGE COLORS! </h1>
<script>
  function black(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.color = 'black' }
  function red(id)  { document.getElementById(id).style.color = 'red' }
</script>
<a id="toggle_uninitialized" href="javascript:void(0)" ondblclick="(this.id=='toggled') ? this.id='not_toggled' : this.id='toggled';(this.id=='toggled') ? red('color') : black('color');">Double click here</a>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPUnk/2/)

**EDIT**: Changed IDs to not include a space character. Obviously, this solution could be adopted to use ***any*** other existing `anchor element` attributes that are otherwise unneeded (unused) in your code as a toggle switch.

Comment: Except now you're changing the id in to both something that's not unique (if bound to multiple items) or [best case] an invalid id (cannot contain spaces). ;p btw, I didn't down-vote FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
this.style.color = this.style.color == '#000000' ? '#ff0000' : '#000000';
```

(preferably not in an inline event handler)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/t6BUE/

```
<style> .black {color: black;} .red {color: red;}</style>
<div id="color" class="black">test</div>

<input type="button" name="button" value="Change"
onClick="document.getElementById('color').className = (document.getElementById('color').className=='red') ? 'black' : 'red';">
```

I would recommend not checking against the `style.color` value since apparently browsers may change this value. (I just tested on Chrome and it changed #FF0000 to rgb(255,0,0); which makes checking against that value unpredictable in different browsers. I recommend checking the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
ondblclick='(toggle = ! toggle) ? alert("1") : alert("2");'>Double click here</a>
```

before that, you need set toggle to true or false